# changing style for certain divs with the same className

Tags: javascript, css

I have many small divs with the same classname. Every div has a span with text. But since those divs are pretty small long words doesn't fit in them. I want to make font size smaller for those divs that have long words. But my code changes font

```js
var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('tile');
  for (var i=0; i<tiles.length; i++) {
    var textLength = tiles[i].textContent.length;
    var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(tiles[i].querySelector('span')).fontSize;

    if(textLength > 9) {
      tiles[i].querySelector('span').style.fontSize = "0.6rem";
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
    <span>itsaveryverylongword</span>
</div>
<div class="tile">
    <span>bird</span>
</div>
<div class="tile">
    <span>keyboard</span>
</div>
```

size for all divs. How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get span text length

```
var textLength = tiles[i].querySelector('span').textContent.length;
```

`var textLength = tiles[i].textContent.length;` this is length of full  `<span>bird</span>` with `span` tag too.

```js
var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('tile');
  for (var i=0; i<tiles.length; i++) {
    var textLength = tiles[i].querySelector('span').textContent.length;
    console.log(tiles[i].textContent.length);
    var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(tiles[i].querySelector('span')).fontSize;

    if(textLength > 9) {
    console.log(tiles[i].textContent.length);
      tiles[i].querySelector('span').style.fontSize = "0.6rem";
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
    <span>itsaveryverylongword</span>
</div>
<div class="tile">
    <span>bird</span>
</div>
<div class="tile">
    <span>keyboard</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! Could you please answer one more question? I made this js work when the page is loaded. But what if I don't show all those divs when I open the page? I show 10 div onload, but more divs are loaded when I scroll the page. Will this js code affect the div that are loaded when scrolling?

Comment: @j_noe you need to run this script every time after new divs added you can run scrolling event end